# How to draw only points with jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

For now I am using the LineRenderer but I actually need the points, I would like to avoid having the lines in between. Is there a Renderer for that? I tried lineWidth: 0 but the line it still there.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set  `showLine` to `false`

```
seriesDefaults: {    
                showLine:false, 
                },
```

`showLine` property is used ,whether to render the line segments or not

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I couldn't find the answer anywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your plot

```
var plot = $.jqplot(id, [array], {
      axes:{
        xaxis:{
          renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer, 
          tickOptions:{formatString:'%H:%M'},
          min:'June 16, 2008 8:00AM', 
          tickInterval:'2 weeks'
        }
      },
      series:[{lineWidth:1, 
            markerOptions: { style:'none', display: 'none' },
                showMarker:false}],
      seriesColors:["#FF0000"]
      ,grid: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(211, 233, 195)',
            shadow: true
            drawGridLines: true,        
            gridLineColor: '#cccccc',   
            background: '#fffdf6',      
            borderColor: '#999999',     
            borderWidth: 2.0,           
            shadow: true,               
            shadowAngle: 45,            
            shadowOffset: 1.5,          
            shadowWidth: 3,             
            shadowDepth: 3,             
            shadowAlpha: 0.07,  
            renderer: $.jqplot.CanvasGridRenderer, 
            rendererOptions: {}
      }
  });
```

More exaples here : [JQplot examples page](http://www.jqplot.com/examples/line-charts.php)